# Extend a class within a function and keep typings

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend a class inside a function while preserving the typings of the original class.

The function takes a `Model` class and extends it with some extra information, then returns the newly extended class.

I would like to avoid using `any` here because I don't want to lose the typings that `Model` gives you.

```
export default function attach(ModelClass: typeof Model, options: AttachOptions) {
  class AttachedClass extends ModelClass {

     // override some static methods here based on `options`
  }

  return AttachedClass;
}
```

I get this error though

`Return type of exported function has or is using private name 'AttachedClass'. on line 1`

Answer (score 0):

I assume the error is from declaration file generation?

You'll need to annotate the return type of `attach`.  You could declare an interface `AttachMethods` with the methods that are added to the static side of the class and then make the return type `typeof Model & AttachMethods`.  Making the return type dependent on the options is trickier but likely to be possible; I can help with that if you provide more information.